# Python3 for loop with range giving unexpected results during self function calls

Tags: python-3.x, function, for-loop, range

Below is the question I am trying to solve. I am a novice python3 learner and tried below mentioned approach. I am unable to figure out why the second for loop prints "test4" as well and throwing exceptions/errors while I was expecting only "test0" during the last iteration. I am sure there must be many easy ways to solve this problem but I would like to know why it's happening like this with my piece of code? Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in Advance!!

**Question:**

Given an arithmetic expression in Reverse Polish Notation, write a program to evaluate it.

The expression is given as a list of numbers and operands. For example: [5, 3, '+'] should return 5 + 3 = 8.

For example, [15, 7, 1, 1, '+', '-', '/', 3, '*', 2, 1, 1, '+', '+', '-'] should return 5, since it is equivalent to ((15 / (7 - (1 + 1))) * 3) - (2 + (1 + 1)) = 5.

You can assume the given expression is always valid.

**Code:**

```
input_list = [15, 7, 1, 1, '+', '-', '/', 3, '*', 2, 1, 1, '+', '+', '-']
input_list_copy = input_list[:]

def eval_expr():
    print("before")
    print(input_list)
    print(input_list_copy, range(len(input_list_copy)))

    for i in range(len(input_list_copy)):
        # print(i)
        # print(type(input_list_copy[i]))
        if type(input_list_copy[i]) == str:
            sub_list = input_list_copy[i - 2:i + 1]
            print(sub_list)
            sub_expr = f"({sub_list[0]}{sub_list[2]}{sub_list[1]})"
            print(sub_expr)
            sub_expr_val = eval(sub_expr)
            # print(type(sub_expr_val))
            print(f"output:{sub_expr_val}")
            input_list_copy[i - 2:i + 1] = [sub_expr_val]

            print("after")
            print(input_list)
            print(input_list_copy, range(len(input_list_copy)))
            break

    for j in range(len(input_list_copy)):
        print(f"test{j}")
        if type(input_list_copy[j]) == str:
            # print(type(input_list_copy[j]))
            eval_expr()

eval_expr()
```

[image: Last Iteration]

[image: Index error]

**Updated Solution Code:**

```
input_list = [15, 7, 1, 1, '+', '-', '/', 3, '*', 2, 1, 1, '+', '+', '-']
input_list_copy = input_list[:]


def eval_expr():
    print(f"length : {len(input_list_copy)}")
    if len(input_list_copy)!=1:
        # print("before")
        # print(input_list)
        # print(input_list_copy, range(len(input_list_copy)))

        for i in range(len(input_list_copy)):
            # print(i)
            # print(type(input_list_copy[i]))
            if type(input_list_copy[i]) == str:
                sub_list = input_list_copy[i - 2:i + 1]
                # print(sub_list)
                sub_expr = f"({sub_list[0]}{sub_list[2]}{sub_list[1]})"
                # print(sub_expr)
                sub_expr_val = eval(sub_expr)
                # print(type(sub_expr_val))
                # print(f"output:{sub_expr_val}")
                input_list_copy[i - 2:i + 1] = [sub_expr_val]

                # print("after")
                # print(input_list)
                # print(input_list_copy, range(len(input_list_copy)))
                break

        eval_expr()


eval_expr()

print(f"Result={input_list_copy[0]}")
```

Comment: Add a condition at
`if len(input_list_copy) > j:`

Comment: or you use: `if type(input_list_copy[j] if len(input_list_copy) > j else 0) == str:`

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @balajik I used something similar by removing the second loop as updated in the Solution part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you'd expect last iteration prints `test0` only.
`test4` prints that the statement is coming from the very first call of the `eval_expr()`  function.

Since this is a recursive call when you reach the last iteration the program tries to complete the remaining iteration.
`(last_iteration -1)`, `(last_iteration -2)`, `(last_iteration -3)`... until the very first call.

When you called the `j for-loop` for the first time `input_list_copy` would have had value:
`[15, 7, 2, '-', '/', 3, '*', 2, 1, 1, '+', '+', '-']`.
So the `j for-loop` would have been set to **execute 13 times**.

The recursive call of the `eval_expr()` function started when it reaches `'-'` `(j=3)` in `input_list_copy`.

After completing all recursive function calls the control goes to first `j for-loop`  call where it is set to **execute 13 times**.

when the 4th iteration started it prints "test4" statement, but by this time `input_list_copy` list is being updated as a single member list.

So when you try to access element that is not available in `input_list_copy` you get: `IndexError: list index out of range`.